# how to enable GUI mode in oracle linux 6

Tags: linux, oracle

WE are trying to opening Graphical user interface services , but not able to open in Oracle Linux 6.10. Please provide any solution

how to enable GUI mode in oracle linux 6.1 .

Comment: Do you have the graphical user interface installed? We install Oracle Linux 6 without the graphical interface as the installations are on headless servers. Try `yum groupinstall basic-desktop` for example.

Answer (score 0):

If it was installed as server mode it will not have a GUI by default.

You need to select one to install using yum

to get a list of yum packages that could work run

```
yum grouplist
```

If available then run

```
yum groupinstall "Server with GUI"
```

or

```
yum groupinstall "X Window System"
```

To see the GUI switch mode with

```
init 5
```